# jQuery count number of input fields that have a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a value is entered in an input field, I want to count how many input fields **in that row** have a value in total.

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="input input1" />
    <input type="text" class="input input2" />
    <input type="text" class="input input2" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="input input1" />
    <input type="text" class="input input2" />
    <input type="text" class="input input2" />
</div>
```

I'm trying following but I think problem is with the loop.

```
$('.input').keyup(function () {

    var field = $(this).parent().children('.input');
    var count = 0;

    $(field).each(function (i) {
        var len = $(field).val().length;        
        if (len > 0 ) {
            count++;
        }
    });

  alert(count);

});
```

**JSFiddle** link: http://jsfiddle.net/18cpotw6/

Comment: off topic: You might find it easier to user variable names that match what they contain - in this case `var fields = ..list of inputs..`  then `$(fields).each(function (i, e) { var field = $(e); field.val().. }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `$(field).val()`, you're retrieving the value of the *first* element in the `field` jQuery collection. Use `$(this).val()` instead:

```js
$('.input').keyup(function() {

  var field = $(this).parent().children('.input');
  var count = 0;

  $(field).each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      count++;
    }
  });

  console.log(count);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="input input1" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
</div>

<div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="input input1" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
</div>
```

You can also remove the `i` parameter, since it's not being used.

Answer (score 2):

You looped through the fields you have found but used the same **field** variable which contains all the fields to find the values. Instead you have to do **this**-

```
$('.input').keyup(function () {

    var field = $(this).parent().find('.input');
    var count = 0;

    $(field).each(function (i) {
        var len = $(this).val().length;     
        if (len > 0 ) {
            count++;
        }
    });

  alert(count);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashhaq12345/yxrwdkfL/3/

Answer (score 2):

From reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481539/jquery-check-if-input-exists-and-has-a-value), you can also create a custom selector and then only get `input` which has values.

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].hasValue = function(el, index, match) {
  return el.value != "";
};

$('.input').keyup(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().find('input:hasValue').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="input input1" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
</div>

<div class="row">
  <input type="text" class="input input1" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
  <input type="text" class="input input2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/). You first select the elements, and then filter them on if they have a value or not:

```js
function example(){
    const $row = $('.row');
    const length = $row.find('input').filter(function() {
        return this.value.length !== 0;
    }).length;
    
    console.log(length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <input class="someSelection" />
    <input class="someSelection" value="foo" />
    <input class="someSelection" />
    <input class="someSelection" value="bar"/>
</div>
<button onclick="example()">Press me!</button>
```